# MatTabGroup not changing tab programatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 14.1.1
I've the following mat-tab-group in my component:

```
<mat-tab-group
  mat-align-tabs="end"
  dynamicHeight
  preserveContent="true">
  <!-- table -->
  <mat-tab label="Tabla">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <web-apps-task-table [columns]="this.columns" [data]="this.data"></web-apps-task-table>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <!-- Gantt -->
  <mat-tab label="Gráfico">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <web-apps-tasks-viewer (anchorSelected)="onAnchorSelected($event)"></web-apps-tasks-viewer>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And I'm trying to change tabs programatically. I've tried several approachs.

- With ViewChild

  ```
  <mat-tab-group #tabGroup

  @ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup!: MatTabGroup;

  changeTab() {
    this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  ```
- Using a variable and two way binding:

  ```
  <mat-tab-group
    [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTab"

  ...
  changeTab() {
    this.selectedTab = 0;
  }
  ```
- Using a variable, one way binding and event:

  ```
  <mat-tab-group
    [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTab"
    (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)"
  ```
- Using a FormControl as specified here https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples#tab-group-dynamic

None has worked. The variables and properties are updated but when I overwrite them, nothing happens.

Updated: The following works when placed in ngOnInit:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Changing tab to 1");
  this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = 1;
}, 1000);
```

If I try the very same code later on after a user action, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the event/function call was running inside ngZone.runOutsideAngular, that's the reason the component wasn't being properly updated.

All methods work after removing runOutsideAngular.